# Eclipse SVN subversive does not commit

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I am using svn repository under Eclipse. The project repository is imported and shown under *"SVN Repository Exploring"*.

Now, when I change a file and do right click on this **file -> Team -> Commit** the commit window opens. There I can write any comment but I do **NOT** see the changed file under the *Resource table*!

Therefore I can not commit anything although I changed the file.
With SVN tortoise I can commit the changed file without problem.

What could be the problem here?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Execute an svn cleanup and make sure if it is a newly created file that you have added it to svn.

Comment: it is not a new file added to svn. A cleanup was not the solution.. What I see is a small icon with an exclamation mark (!) for the selected file.

Comment: Sounds like a conflict. You updated the file while id was already in a modified state and the automatic merge failed. Check if the menu entry "Mark as Merged" is active. If yes, apply it.

Comment: no this entry is not active! Pls see all entries above.